# Can't see my plugin in Terminal when running auval -a command

Tags: macos, audiounit

I'm currently following this tutorial:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Tutorial-BuildingASimpleEffectUnitWithAGenericView/Tutorial-BuildingASimpleEffectUnitWithAGenericView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003278-CH5-SW2

And I'm at the stage where I type auval -a into terminal to see if OSX recognises my audio unit bundle. Well... it doesn't. I've checked that the path is correct and it seems to be but I still can't see it in Terminal.

Has this happened to anyone else? What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Your machine is likely compiling for 64 bit architecture. Try this instead:

```
auval -64 -a
```

Also see [here](http://www.squishycat.com/audio-unit-development/getting-started-developing-audio-units-on-mac-os-x-and-xcode-4-my-experiences-as-a-beginner).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the name of the executable file in the Plist matches the project name. I had a small typo (TremoloUnita instead of TremoloUnit, project is called TremoloUnit) and it didn't work.